# python socket: sending and receiving 16 bytes

Tags: python, sockets

See edits below.

I have two programs that communicate through sockets.  I'm trying to send a block of data from one to the other.  This has been working with some test data, but is failing with others.

```
s.sendall('%16d' % len(data))
s.sendall(data)
print(len(data))
```

sends to

```
size = int(s.recv(16))
recvd = ''
while size > len(recvd):
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data: 
        break
    recvd += data
print(size, len(recvd))
```

At one end:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((server_ip, port))
```

and the other:

```
c = socket.socket()
c.bind(('', port))
c.listen(1)
s,a = c.accept()
```

In my latest test, I sent a 7973903 byte block and the receiver reports size as 7973930.

Why is the data block received off by 27 bytes?

Any other issues?

Python 2.7 or 2.5.4 if that matters.

EDIT:  Aha - I'm probably reading past the end of the send buffer.  If remaining bytes is less than 1024, I should only read the number of remaining bytes.  Is there a standard technique for this sort of data transfer?  I have the feeling I'm reinventing the wheel.

EDIT2: I'm screwing up by reading the next file in the series. I'm sending file1 and the last block is 997 bytes.  Then I send file2, so the recv(1024) at the end of file1 reads the first 27 bytes of file2.

I'll start another question on how to do this better.

Thanks everyone.  Asking and reading comments helped me focus.

Comment: You don't say what protocol you're using.  Is it TCP or UDP?

Comment: "I sent a 7973903 byte block".  How do you know this?   "receiver reported size as 7973930" If this was the first 16 bytes, then that's the real size.  Why do you think the size is not what the receiver received as the first 16 bytes?  Please provide some logs or other information to show what's going on.

Comment: See the latest edit.  I have print statements at each end. I receive the number with the first recv, then the data with the loop.

Comment: "I send the number 7973903 and the receiver reads the number as 7973930."  Please include actual log output from your actual execution to substantiate this.  Also, when reading in the size on the receiver, use the `repr()` function to print the string before applying `int()` to it.

Comment: I'm printing to screen, so no logs.  See latest edit, the size is being communicated correctly, but len(recvd) is the other number.  repr() doesn't help.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Aha - I'm probably reading past the end of the send buffer.  If remaining bytes is less than 1024, I should only read the number of remaining bytes.

Comment: I don't think so. What is the data you are sending? Is it binary data? Since recv returns a string, is it possible that it encoded some non-ascii char into something else?

Comment: "I'm printing to screen, so no logs."  What?  Redirect stdout to a file.  Or write to a file.

Comment: "repr() doesn't help?"  It's not supposed to "help".  It's supposed to produce output that you can add to the question so we can see the entire 16 bytes as actually read by the actual receiver.  It doesn't "fix" anything.  It's for diagnosing the problem.  Please collect the output we're asking for and **update** the question with the actual output.

Comment: @Jingshao: the problem is that I'm reading from the next chunk of data being sent.  Binary data.

Comment: @S.Lott: repr() doesn't help in that it doesn't reveal any more information than print

Comment: @foosion: "repr() doesn't ... reveal any more information than print".  False.  `repr()` proves that unprintable ASCII characters aren't confusing `int()` conversion.  `repr()` is absolutely essential, critical, necessary and mandatory for debugging this kind of thing.  It totally helps because it provides absolute proof of the *exact* byte values being received.  It's critical.  It's important.

Comment: One more question, is the client and server on the same machine? Could it be network problem? Does this happen every time?

Comment: FYI, if you've found the answer then you should post on your own question with your answer and accept it, so that this is no longer marked as unanswered :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, the line

```
size = int(s.recv(16))
```

might read less than 16 bytes — it is unlikely, I will grant, but possible depending on how the network buffers align. The `recv()` call argument is a *maximum* value, a limit on how much data you are willing to receive. But you might only receive one byte. The operating system will generally give you control back once at least one byte has arrived, maybe (depending on the OS and on how busy the CPU is) after waiting another few milliseconds in case a second packet arrives with some further data, so that it only has to wake you up once instead of twice.

So you would want to say instead (to do the simplest possible loop; other variants are possible):

```
data = ''
while len(data) < 16:
    more = s.recv(16 - len(data))
    if not more:
        raise EOFError()
    data += more
```

This is indeed a wheel nearly everyone re-invents because it is so often needed. And your own code needs it a second time: your `while` loop needs its `recv()` to count down, asking for smaller and smaller limits until finally it has received exactly the number of bytes that were promised, and no more.